# How can I have files in Git that don't sync with remote, or get bypassed when deployed?

Tags: git

My problem is that when I develop websites I often have huge photoshop-files or raw images that take several gigabytes of space. When I deploy my simple wordpress site using Git and Beanstalk, I would like to avoid pushing and deploying these files.

Is it possible to have them under git but not push them? I'd still like to have them under git because there are often new versions of them coming etc.

I'm using Git Tower as I'm just a designer.

Thanks!

Comment: Git is not really well-suited to tracking binary files like image files, because it can't efficiently compress and store them in the same way as it can with text files. The end result is that Git repos that store frequently changing binary files become larger and larger in storage size over time. I've heard that [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) was made to help with this, but I'm not sure if it can help you with your deployment problem.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to put the large files in a separate repository.

**Edit:** You might also consider adding the psd files to `.git/info/exclude` but *only* in the remote repository. Unlike `.gitignore`, this file is not changed when you push to the remote repo. (Normally this is not what you want, hence `.gitignore`, but in this case it is useful.)
The disadvantage of this trick would be that it is not obvious why certain files are ignored. And it wouldn't transfer when you clone the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the heavy files on your local repository but not on the remote?

If so, you might want to create a `gitignore` file that lists your `.psd` files. Read the [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more info.

If you want to have them on your git but not deployed every time you make an update, maybe having them on another branch is the right way to go.

Comment: Ignoring the files will prevent them from being committed locally.

Comment: @Chris I was considering both solutions separately.

Comment: @SirCelsius A `.gitignore` file would be copied to the remote. Using `.git/info/exclude` in the remote as I've described in my answer should work though.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a job for git-annex.

https://git-annex.branchable.com